# Use javascript in css sheets and html element id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing in Javascript, css, html..

In this moment I have a lot of css classes referenced in my Javascript code and now I'm creating "constants" with the names of the css classes. This is because if I want to change the name of one of this classes, I should just do it in one place.

My questions are two.

The first is

- Can I use Javascript variables to define classes and ids into the css file and ids of elements inside html documents. Some like this

For CSS (replacing "&&js_var&&" by a sentence that sets the id to the value of javascript variable)

```
. &&js_var&& {
   /* css definition */
}
```

for HTML (replacing "&&js_var&&" by a sentence that sets the id to the value of javascript variable)

```
<div id="&&js_var&&"></div>
```

The second is,

- in case that it can be done, is this good programming practice?

Comment: Why do you expect to change the CSS class names frequently? The content of the CSS class (the style rules) itsrlf - I understand. But why would the name change frequently?

Comment: I don't get it either - and I'm guessing your using some type of IDE to code in , you can't just do Find All , Replace All of a certain text, why do you progrmatically need to change class names?

Comment: I don't know why you would like to do so... However if you want/need to you could use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

Comment: If you want to apply particular css for an element at any point of time, you can add it in a css class and apply that class for the the element… (*you probably know that already*) any particular reason for changing the text in css file itself..?

Comment: Because I'm modified a application and I'm adding or duplicating elements, e.g. If i divide a areatext in two textarea, the id before was "textarea" and after "textarea_1" and "textarea_2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question - **Can I use Javascript variables to define classes and ids into the css file and ids of elements inside html documents.**

Answer: No, not in the way you are thinking. Css content are not subject to dynamic manipulation, but are plain text rendered by the browser. You could, in a certain way, replace some of the text content and re-render the style using some techniques, but it falls into your second question.

---

Second question - **in case that it can be done, is this good programming practice?**

Answer: Not at all. Css stylesheets are designed to center the visual styles applied to html elements in one place, causing every visual change to have a cascading effect on every page refering to this stylesheet (there is where the name .css come from, "cascading"). The whole point is that class names and element's ids are static, so the cascading would make sense.

---

I hope it helped some way...

Comment: I thought it was as you say but I wanted to know by another. I wanted to centralize all names in a constants file and to change their names because some names were not very good (e.g. they are not descriptive).